# What regular expression needs to be used to extract a particular value from an HTML tag?

Tags: java

What regular expression can be used to extract the value of `src` attribute in the `iframe` tag?

Comment: javascript instead of java?

Comment: regex should not be used for parsing something as complex and *wierd* as html document. use library meant to be used for that kind of task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 4):

If you really are using Java (not JavaScript) and you only have the `iframe`, you can try the regular expression:

```
(?<=src=")[^"]*(?<!")
```

e.g.:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=src=\")[^\"]*(?<!\")");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<iframe name=\"I1\" id=\"I1\" marginwidth=\"1\" marginheight=\"1\" height=\"430px\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"report.htm?view=country=us\">";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()
    );  // prints "false"

    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
report.htm?view=country=us
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say look into dom parsing. from there it would be extremely similar to the javascript answer.
Dom parser will turn the html into a document from there you can do:

iframe = document.getElementById("I1");
src = iframe.getAttribute("src");

Answer (score 0):

Regex is little bit costlier do not use it until you have other simple solution, in java try this

```
String src="<iframe name='I1' id='I1' marginwidth='1' marginheight='1'" + 
" height='430px' width='100%' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'" +
" src='report.htm?view=country=us'>";

int position1 = src.indexOf("src") + 5;
System.out.println(position1);

int position2 = src.indexOf("\'", position1);
System.out.println(position2);

System.out.println(src.substring(position1, position2));
```

Output:

```
134
160
report.htm?view=country=us
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you meant javascript instead of java:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("I1");
var src = iframe.getAttribute("src");
alert(src); //outputs the value of the src attribute
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure he wants to use Java.

Comment: He stated he is using Java.

Answer (score -1):

```
 src="(.*?)"
```

The regular expression will match `src="report.htm?view=country=us"`, but you will find only the part between the `"` in the first (and only) submatch.

When you only want to match src-attributes when they are in an iframe, do this:

```
<iframe.*?src="(.*?)".*?>
```

but there are certain corner-cases where this could fail due to the inherently non-regular nature of HTML. See the top answer to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for an amusing rant about this problem.

Comment: @djechlin I did point out that it can't parse any HTML, but it will parse the HTML in the question. I also think that your criticism would be more constructive when you would offer a better solution instead of just complaining.

Comment: Comments that point out problems in solutions are constructive. They tell the reader "this won't work." The better solution is to use an HTML parser.